# Trying to make an image a circle in Gutenberg

Tags: css, block-editor

Gutenberg allows extra CSS styles for an image.

I want to make the image a circle and I thought this CSS would work:

```
img.imgcircular {
-webkit-clip-path: circle(15.7% at 50% 50%);
clip-path: circle(15.7% at 50% 50%);
}
```

And the class on the image is "imgcircular"

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.css` try to add the following :

```
.is-style-circle-mask img,
.is-style-rounded img {
-webkit-clip-path: circle(15.7% at 50% 50%);
 clip-path: circle(15.7% at 50% 50%);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great thank you very much!